# XML Error while submitting _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ feed to Amazon MWS

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xsd-validation

I'm getting error code 25 in response to this feed submission below and I can't figure out what is wrong with my XML.  I've looked at the xsd and still haven't been able to identify what I'm submitting that is incorrectly formatted.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='amzn-envelope.xsd'>
        <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>**REMOVED**</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
        <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
        <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
                <MerchantOrderID>102-4429901-2897066</MerchantOrderID>
                <MerchantFulfillmentID>1</MerchantFulfillmentID>
                <FulfillmentDate>2015-06-15T21:30:00Z+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
                <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>1Z089F6Y0398251296</ShipperTrackingNumber>
                </FulfillmentData>
<Item>
                    <MerchantOrderItemID>FLUK_EFG120C</MerchantOrderItemID>
                    <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>FLUK_EFG120C</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
        </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: I ended up finding my error.  The 'Z' in my fulfillment date was throwing the error.  Took it out and boom it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my error. The 'Z' in my fulfillment date was throwing the error. Took it out and boom it worked!